# Google Visualization full browser window

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have this google visualization and I would like to maki it full screen on my browser window: http://cl.ly/image/1y0U1m1o2m0m

The code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>

    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var a = <?=$elos?>;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a);

        var options = {
          title: 'blah blah blah',
          //curveType: "function",
          width: $(window).width(),
          height: $(window).height(),
          vAxis: {
            minValue:800,
            maxValue:2000,
            textStyle: {color: 'black'}
          },
          legend:{position: 'none'}
        };



        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, options);
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visualization"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even though it is set to window size and it creates a rect for the size of the window there is a lot of free space around the chart

Answer (score 0):

To make chart be full page size:

```
chartArea: {width: '90%', height: '90%'}
```